# Hammer.js - support single and double tap without delay

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am using [Hummer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) to handle single and double taps, both gestures are recognised with a delay of a few hundred milliseconds.
as demonstrated here [(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/michabeeri/6xv2ds9m/)

```
var hammertime = new Hammer.Manager(containerElement);
hammertime.add(new Hammer.Tap({event: 'doubletap', taps: 2}));
hammertime.add(new Hammer.Tap({event: 'singletap'}));
hammertime.get('singletap').requireFailure('doubletap');
hammertime.on("doubletap", onDoubleTap);
hammertime.on("singletap", onSingleTap);
```

The single tap delay is unavoidable since it must wait to make sure this is not actually a double tap. but there is no reason for the double-tap delay.
I could remove the requireFailure setup and handle this sort of logic myself has demonstrated here [(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/michabeeri/n64z8x3g/).

```
var hammertime = new Hammer.Manager(containerElement);
hammertime.add(new Hammer.Tap({event: 'doubletap', taps: 2}));
hammertime.add(new Hammer.Tap({event: 'singletap'}));
//hammertime.get('singletap').requireFailure('doubletap');
hammertime.on("doubletap", onDoubleTap);
hammertime.on("singletap", setupSingleTapTimeout);

function setupSingleTapTimeout() {
    cancelSingleTapTimeout();
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(onSingleTap, 300);
}

function cancelSingleTapTimeout() {
  if(timeoutId !== null) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = null;
  }
}

function onDoubleTap() {
    cancelSingleTapTimeout();
    ...
}
```

But i would much rathe keep the separation of concerns and leave this kind of work for Hammer, which also seem like something it should know how to do ..

Those anyone knows how to achieve this with hammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After diving into the library code i realized setting requireFailure between two gestures implicitly requiresFailure also in the opposite direction.
In my case single-tap will wait for double-tap to fail but also double-tap will wait for single-tap to fail which makes no sense and cause double-tap to suffer the penalty of waiting.

There is however a way to drop the requireFailure condition in a single direction using

```
hammertime.get('doubletap').dropRequireFailure('singletap')
```

The complete example ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michabeeri/g91qx4bq/))